# Hive/Impala. Query to get rows in ranges which accomplish a condition

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, impala

I am pretty much new to Impala/hive querying, and I am not very sure on how to make this one.

The objective of this query is obtaining the data of defined ranges (2 points where a condition is accomplished).

To be clearer, we have a table with  3 columns : Date, A and B.

We order the table by Date, and we want to get all rows from all intervals between two A=1 which do not have any B=1 in it. (So, ranges are between every two A=1 and condition is that there is no B=1 in them).

I painted the concept I am looking for so it gets clearer.

Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_zAJFzI2slWQnRwN2gwWk9NSG8

Comment: Please supply a reasonable data sample (text, format it using ctrl+k)

Comment: Is it possible that A=1 and B=1 at the same point?

Comment: Lets asume we can not have A=1 and B=1 at the same point,  to make things easier.  I could provide a data table (which i should create,  as this is just a simplified query concept  which i would have to adapt to my real needs) if this would really help giving an answer. Make me know how many rows are needed and which text format would you like ( i would probably make a program to automatically generate them).

Comment: Are the rows with A=1 also required?

Comment: About 10 rows that reflects different use-cases. INSERT statement would be ideal.

Comment: Rows with A=1 would not be requiered in this case,  but it does not matter if they are inserted in,  if this would make query easier. Thanks for the answer,  going to check it asap and give a feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  dt,A,B

from   (select  dt,A,B
               ,max (case when A=1 then dt end) over p  as p_A1_dt
               ,max (case when B=1 then dt end) over p  as p_B1_dt
               ,min (case when A=1 then dt end) over f  as f_A1_dt
               ,min (case when B=1 then dt end) over f  as f_B1_dt

        from    mytable

        window  p as (order by dt rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
               ,f as (order by dt rows between 1 following and unbounded following)
        ) t

where   (   p_A1_dt >= p_B1_dt
        or  (   p_A1_dt is not null
            and p_B1_dt is null
            )
        )

    and (   f_A1_dt <= f_B1_dt
        or  (   f_A1_dt is not null
            and f_B1_dt is null
            )
        ) 

    and coalesce(A,-1) <> 1
```

---

Same, but without the `window` decleration

```
select  dt,A,B

from   (select  dt,A,B
               ,max (case when A=1 then dt end) over (order by dt rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)  as p_A1_dt
               ,max (case when B=1 then dt end) over (order by dt rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)  as p_B1_dt
               ,min (case when A=1 then dt end) over (order by dt rows between 1 following and unbounded following)  as f_A1_dt
               ,min (case when B=1 then dt end) over (order by dt rows between 1 following and unbounded following)  as f_B1_dt

        from    mytable
        ) t

where   (   p_A1_dt >= p_B1_dt
        or  (   p_A1_dt is not null
            and p_B1_dt is null
            )
        )

    and (   f_A1_dt <= f_B1_dt
        or  (   f_A1_dt is not null
            and f_B1_dt is null
            )
        ) 

    and coalesce(A,-1) <> 1
```

Comment: Ok, i checked it and i am getting this error in line 4: over p as p_A1_dt ^ Encountered: IDENTIFIER Expected: ( CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Comment: I am using impala version 2.3.0-cdh 5.5.4

Comment: This was tested on hive 2.1.1

Comment: I am testing it on hive. It gets forever to make the query, so i suppose that someone is using the data server atm (and this making the query on a reduced table with a limit of 5). I will have to use the hive query later, but if it is ok with you, could you adapt it to impala so i can make some testing? It is much faster for me actually. If you prefer not doing it, thank you anyway, you were very helpful. I will accept the answer whenever i can test it.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, i really appreciate that. It returns results in impala. Tomorrow i will run it on a big database and see results graphically, so i can make sure i get no outlier.